# Ubuntu VirtualBox resized hard disk not being recognized by command df -h

Tags: server, virtualbox, gparted, resize

I tried to resize a virtual HD in VirtualBox by first using the builtin resize function, then by adjusting the partition size of /dev/sda to use all the remaining space with a live boot of GParted. Vbox shows the HDD as being 45 GB (the full resized capacity) but **df-h** continues to show the old HD size.  I have shut down the VM multiple times using the ACPI shutdown command.

What else is needed to make Ubuntu 20 recognize the larger HDD size?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20. An accurate version number would be the first step.

Comment: You have increased the disk size and the partition size. What you describe suggests that you have not increased the size of the filesystem. You can do that with the `resize2fs` command. Look up the man page, it’s very easy and can be done with the partition mounted

Comment: David, this is what I was referring to:   Ubuntu Server v20.04.4 LTS
https://ubuntu.com/download/server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that you need to resize the filesystem you need to proceed as follows.

1. Backup any data that you cannot afford to lose. You shouldn’t lose anything but just to be safe. Skip this step if there is no important data on this VM.
2. Open a terminal and use the command `lsblk` This should allow you to identify the partition that you want to resize. It will be something like  /dev/sda1.
3. Again in the terminal use the command `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1` Substitute the partition name  you found at step 2 in this command.
4. The command should extend the filesystem to fill the partition.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like /sda3 is the partition of interest.
When I run 'sudo resize2fs /dev/sda3' ,   I get this error:
"resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda3
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock."

Comment: Are you using LVM in this VM? Please add your `lsblk` output to the question

Comment: lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2253
loop1                       7:1    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2284
loop2                       7:2    0 61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1361
loop3                       7:3    0 61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1376
loop4                       7:4    0 67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21835

Comment: loop5                       7:5    0 43.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14978
loop6                       7:6    0 67.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22526
sda                         8:0    0 45.7G  0 disk
|-sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
|-sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
`-sda3                      8:3    0 44.7G  0 part
  `-ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0    9G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom

Comment: Sorry for not knowing what LVM even is... in my limited linux experience, this is the first time I've seen "lvm".  I'm running Ubuntu 20 Server in a VM, headless.

Comment: You are using LVM so the process is different. The space you created on sda3 needs to be added to your LVM volume group. See this tutorial https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/ You need to follow the process below “Extending Volume Group”. That includes the final resize2fs step but you need to extend the volume group first. Use the various commands in the tutorial to confirm the state of your volume group including how much is available to add.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you.  I didn't even know what logical, physical volumes were in Linux.  It must be default for the server version.

Comment: I increased my VDI from 64GB to 128GB, but I still seeing 64GB in my ubuntu guest machine as a physical disk size, so it is impossible for me to expand the partition via gparded. Any idea?

Comment: @albin  See the link in my comment above. Most of it may not be relevant but sounds like you need to do the resize2fs stage. You can always ask your own question and provide more information about your situation